# How is the time of sunrise and sunset determined?

Tags: the-sun, time

If I do a quick Google search for `amsterdam sunrise`, I immediately get the time back: `6:42 AM`.

How is this time calculated?

(I mean how it is really calculated, not how Google get it, with is probably from a table. Of course I mean sunrises and sunsets in the future, not from the past. $:)$)

Comment: Do you know about the [sunrise equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation)? Scroll down to [the bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_equation#Calculate_sunrise_and_sunset).

Comment: Thanks, no. From what I read I can calculate $\omega_o = \text{acos}{(-\tan(\phi)\tan(\delta))}$ with in my case $\phi = 50^{\circ}$. How do I get the value of $\delta$ and how do I convert $\omega_o$ to HH:MM (hours and minutes)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $\delta$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Calculations). You just need to find the solar declination of the day. $\omega_o$ is a spatial coordinate, not a length of time. For the date, you need to do a bunch of intermediate calculations, then find the [Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: You can use the CSPICE libraries to calculate it exactly, and USNO publishes it for a wide variety of locations, but I think you're asking: what simple equation does this so that websites can use it (or use JavaScript) without having to do super-precise calculations?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to ask. 